# Missing } inserted in tipa

Tags: tikz-pgf, tipa, tikz-shape

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgflibraryshapes}

\newcommand*\chiuan[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]
\node[draw,ellipse,very thick,fill=white,inner sep=2pt](x){$\displaystyle#1$};\!}

\begin{document}
\textramshorns \textbabygamma
$\uparrow\chiuan{A}$
\end{document}
```

Output `Missing } inserted`. How fix it?

Comment: `\!` is the problem.

Comment: @Ignasi, I deleted it. Good working.

Comment: @Ignasi I think this is a duplicate

Comment: @egreg No problem. If someone finds the duplicate, we can close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space command `\!` is not valid inside command. Delete it.